# Bash: multiple lines with pv - printing get messed up if more lines than terminal height

Tags: bash, terminal, progress

I use pv to monitor the progress of multiple processes. Everything works ok if process count is less than terminal height. If all lines don't fit to terminal window printing gets messed up.

How can fix this? Finished processes can be hidden. Resizing terminal should work without messing up progress bars.

Sample code:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..50}
do
   (dd if=/dev/zero status=none bs=64k count=100000 | pv -cN PV${i} -f -s 6400000k -i 2 | dd status=none bs=1M of=/dev/null ) &
   sleep 0.5
done
wait
```

Comment: You read from /dev/zero and write to /dev/null. It is unclear what you want to achieve.

Comment: It's just for testing how pv behaves and for demonstrating the problem.